# A question about series involving a Sobolev functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open, bounded and smooth. Let $\lambda_j$ and $e_j$, $j\in\mathbb{N}$, be the eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ with zero Dirichlet boundary data on $\partial\Omega$. We suppose that: $|| e_j ||_{L^2(\Omega)}=1$. Let $s\in(0,1)$. Let $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, i want to prove that:
$$ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\lambda_j^s<+\infty, $$
where:
$$(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int_\Omega e_ju\,dx. $$
I have no idea to go on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The inequality should be $\sum_j \lambda_j |(u,e_j)|^2 <\infty$.

Comment: @ Giorgio Metafune. There was a mistake in the question. I have to prove that:$$ \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}(u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2\lambda_j^s<+\infty.$$

Comment: Then this follows from the cases $s=0,1$.

Comment: can you give me the details please ?

Comment: $s=0$ is just Bessel inequality for $u$. Now expand for $u$ with comapct support in $\Omega$ $$-\Delta u=\sum_j (-\Delta u, e_j)e_j=\sum_j (u,-\Delta e_j)e_j=\sum_j -\lambda_j (u,e_j)e_j$$ and use the identity $$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u |^2=-\int_{\Omega} u\Delta u=\sum_j \lambda_j | (u,e_j)|^2$$ by Parseval identity. By density this equality extends to $H^1_0$.

Comment: And for $s\in(0,1)$, how i have to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Giorgio Metafune commented, the result follows by the endpoint cases $s=0,1$ and he proved these 2 cases.

1. Case $s=0$. Here we only use that $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonormal sequence the Bessel inequality gives $\sum (u,e_j)^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$.
2. Case $s=1$. We combine the density of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subset H_0^1(\Omega)$ and the fact that $\{e_j\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ forms an $L^2$ basis. If $u\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ we can (take the classical second derivative) and using 2 integration by parts we have
   $$-\Delta u=\sum_j (-\Delta u, e_j)e_j=\sum_j (u,-\Delta e_j)e_j=\sum_j \lambda_j (u,e_j)e_j.$$
   With another integration by part and the Paserval identity we obtain
   $$
   \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=\int_{\Omega} u(-\Delta u) \,dx= \int_\Omega \sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_j (u,e_j) u e_j \,dx=\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \lambda_j (u,e_j)^2_{L^2(\Omega)}
   $$
   By density we conclude that this is true for all $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$.
3. Case $s\in (0,1)$. We can bound the sum as
   $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty (u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \lambda_j^s  \leq \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty (u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \lambda_j + \sum_{j=1}^N (u,e_j)_{L^2(\Omega)}^2$$
   where we take $N$ such that $\lambda_j\leq 1$ when $j\leq N$. For simplicity I used the fact that $\lambda_j \to +\infty$, but we really do not need this fact and we can split in 2 series with $j$ running in the sets $A=\{j: \lambda_j<1\}$ and its complement.